# How can I put '..' in the paths that we put in the os.listdir parameter?

Tags: python, listdir

I use the `os.listdir` function to (as you can imagine) list the folders and files I have in a folder. As the documentation says, "It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.".

I have a problem with this because my code is meant to be published on GitHub and I don't want everyone to see my entire path and besides, since they don't have the same path, the code doesn't work for them.

So I'm wondering how to get around that.

Thanks!

PS: my folder looks like this: [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bgpb.png). The python code is in the `py` folder and the folders and files I want to access to are in the `Dico` folder.

Comment: Could you provide an example input (what you have) and the desired output (what you would like to have)?

Comment: What do you mean? What's wrong with `os.listdir('../Dico')`?

Comment: @MachineLearner it is very hard to explain and I'm not a native English speaker so I think I can't.

Comment: @a_guest I get the error that I commented on GrandPhuba's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood the documentation. The documentation is saying that the special entries `'.'` and `'..'` will not show up in the **output** of `os.listdir`.

The documentation is not saying that anything special or unusual happens if the *argument* to `os.listdir` includes `..`. You don't need to use absolute paths or any other workaround. If you want a list of the contents of a directory named `Dico` adjacent to the working directory, you can just use

```
os.listdir('../Dico')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out to me. Nevertheless I don't get why my code works when I put an absolute path and doesn't when I don't...

Comment: @Bethoth: Because you're not running where you think you are, so relative paths are relative to a completely different directory from the one you want.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is correct. @Bethoth, try running `os.getcwd()` first to make sure what you current working directory is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the `py` folder, and you want to list the files inside `Dico` which is a folder adjacent to `py`, use the following:

```
os.listdir('../Dico')
```

Comment: it does not work. I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The specified path cannot be found: '../Dico'`

Comment: @Bethoth: That error has nothing to do with what you think it does. That error means you're not running in the `py` directory at all.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I run the file that way: `& "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python.exe" c:/Users/ROMAIN/OneDrive/Projets/Dico-abreviations-et-acronymes/py/recherche.py` (this is automated by Visual Studio Code to run python). I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Moreover, I don't get the error when I use an absolute path.

Comment: @Bethoth the `cwd` (current working directory) is not the one where your script is located, rather where you are running it **from**. Since the path is relative to the script you might get the error if not running in its location. You will not get the error with an absolute path because, well, it is absolute so always valid...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a path relative to the module:

```
import os

path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], '..', 'Dico')
os.listdir(path)
```

If you're preparing a package, for Python 3.7+, you can also use [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources):

```
import importlib

importlib.resources.contents('package.Dico')
```

Comment: I'll try that this afternoon. I'll tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your file structure looks like this.

```
folder---
    py---
  dico---
```

And I am also assuming that you have tried `os.listdir("../dico")` and got an error something similar to this `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`
But let me assure you that the code is correct. the reason for the error can be the following.
If you are running the code from an IDE check the terminal path.
It will be `/yoursystempath/folder/` not `/yoursystempath/folder/py`. this is a common mistake as most IDEs starts the python interpreter at the Project folder level. not at the Script level.
the best way to deal with the paths in python is to create a `rootdir` variable in one of the script files under py folder and import it wherever required.

```python
from os import listdir, path
# this return the abspath to the current folder irrespective of where interpreter starts
curdir = path.abspath(path.join(path.abspath(__file__), path.pardir))
# this will return the rootdir path assuming its one level up.
#in your case it will return abs path for folder
rootdir = path.abspath(path.join(curdir, path.pardir))

#now use rootdir to reference any file in your file structure
#to get to dico use the following
dicoPath = path.abspath(path.join(rootdir,"dico"))
#now use listdir with varible dicoPath
listdir(dicoPath)
```

now if you want to use the rootdir variable in a different script under py folder use the following.

```
from yourFileWhichHasTherootdir import rootdir
```